# Реализация передачи файлов по локальной сети с помощью ftp-сервера на C# или Java

Tags: java, c#, ftp

Как сделать передачу файлов от одного устройства другому, при условии подключения к одной сети Wi-Fi?

Нужно, чтобы при выборе файла (собираемся передать его на другое устройство) запускался ftp-сервер или другая реализация (http) в фоновом режиме, а на экран выводился адрес этого сервера, чтобы скачать этот файл с другого устройства (по этому адресу).

Например: ftp://192.168.2.123:2137 или http://.....:8080

где: *192.168.2...* - ip-адрес устройства

Когда мы вводим данный адрес на другом устройстве(в приложении), либо в браузере, происходит скачивание данного файла.

Подскажите пожалуйста, способы реализации данной задумки, приветствуются примеры в виде кода.

Comment: я на c# делал, нашел в интернете много информации и легко все вышло. Не знаю, как будет с Java.  Вот пример как загрузать файл по ftp https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms229715(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151680/upload-file-on-ftp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте класс, реализующий TCP или UDP соккеты, и уже через них работайте. Все достаточно тривиально. Для веба, можно передавать веб-заголовки, соответственно, на сервере проверять, если есть подключение, то пытаемся отправить ему файл. Можете прочитать спецификацию FTP и соответственно, реализовать подобную технологию на соккетах в шарпе. Примеров кода tcp сервера и локального http сервера полно в интернете. Несколько ссылок есть на хабре.

Comment: Здравствуйте, может вы сможете подсказать по моей похожей проблеме: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/795261/c-ftp-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8